# How to show a linearly independent subset of one vector space is linearly independent after a linear transformation to another vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

If there exists a linear transformation from vector space $U$ to $V$, $T:U \rightarrow V$. Show that $T(X)$ is a L.I subset where $X \subseteq U$ and $X$ is L.I.

Not sure how to show this, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Any assumption on the linear transformation?

Comment: I think you mean $X \subseteq U$ and the claim is false.The projection of the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$ onto the $x$-axis maps the linearly independent set $\{(1, 0), (2, 2)\}$ onto the linearly dependent set $\{1, 2\}$.

Comment: Presumably this should be for $X$ a linearly independent subset of $U$?

Comment: This is not true it is entirely possible that $T$ is not injective in which $T(X)$ may not be linearly independent. Are you sure that you are not missing any assumptions about $T$.

Comment: Sorry I edited yes @B.Mehta this is assuming $X$ is a L.I subset of $U$

Comment: @SharathZotis Also it should probably include that $T$ is injective also?

Answer (score 2):

This is just not true. consider $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and take $X=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ for a counterexample.

In the case where $T$ is *injective* on the other hand, it has trivial kernel.

Consider any linear combination
$$a_1(Tx_1)+\dots a_n (Tx_n)=0$$ 
and use linearity to show that this linear combination has to have $a_1 =\dots =a_n=0$ for any linearly independent $x_1, \dots x_n$.